# orientação da pagina com um menu dropdown

Tags: html, menu, dropdown

Tenho em uma pagina do meu *site* um menu `dropdown` com uma lista da bandas de rock. Quado vc clica no menu ele "dropa" para baixo mostrando a lista, clicando em alguma banda dessa lista ele fecha esse menu `dropdown` e traz em uma `div` a baixo as informações da banda selecionada. Só que quando selecionado uma banda da parte inferior desse menu ele não sobe a pagina para o começo das informações da banda, ele fica no meio das informações.

Gostaria de saber como fazer ele ir para o topo dessas informações. Ah, já tentei fazer uma ancoragem no `menu` e nas `info`, mas ele não vai para a parte da ancoragem. Se alguém quiser dar uma olhada no `menu` em ação a pagina é essa: http://fraturaexposta.esy.es/HTML/Paginas/dicas.php .
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Após uma busca encontrei o código responsável pelo evento.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#banda a").click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $( this ).attr('href');
    $("#div1").load( href +" #div1");
    });
});
```

Primeiramente, esse código não precisa estar dentro do `$(document).ready`, pois não é executado imediatamente.

Você quer voltar ao início da div após o `.load`, então você deve adicionar uma função anônima como parâmetro no seu evento:

```
$("#div1").load( href +" #div1", function(){
    $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
});
```

Isso vai forçar o scroll ao início da div usando uma animação rápida.

Comment: no caso só precisaria adicionar esse codigo no arquivo da função do evento?

Comment: tentei adicionar esse codigo de tudo quanto é forma mas ele para de funcionar a função ou não faz nada de diferente. é que essas informações da banda ele puxa de um div dentro de uma pagina que funciona na versão mobile do site, no caso ele puxa a div que tem a informação da banda para dentro da div do site para Desktop.

Comment: Sim, eu entendi isso.

Comment: esse código que eu mandei vc coloca no lugar do `$('#div1').load(`

Comment: broder, eu coloquei ele la mas não funcionou, ele parou de chamar a div que tem a informação da banda para o site e te abrindo direto  pagina onde ta essa div.

Comment: eu usei o codigo assim:
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#banda a").click(function( e ){

 e.preventDefault();

 var href = $( this ).attr('href');

 $("#div1").load( href +" #div1", function(){

      $(this).animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");

 });

});



$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#banda a").click(function(){

        $("#panel").hide("slow");

    });

});